# remove column/row of subplots from Matplotlib figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a library function which generates a figure with a 5x5 grid of subplots, using pyplot. In some instances, I'd like to remove some of the columns or lines to give more space to whichever subplots are more rlevant in some particular scenario.

I've found that I can delete subplots after the fact, using `fig.delaxes(ax)`.
However, that just leaves an empty space where the subplot was, even if I delete a whole row or column of subplots this way, change the spacings between subplots, redraw or use `fig.tight_layout()`.

Is there a method to get Matplotlib to close those gaps?
I could probably edit the code which generates the figures to skip the rows/columns in question, but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can set the height_ratios after the fact:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axs = plt.subplots(3, 5, constrained_layout=True)

for i in range(5):
    axs[1, i].set_xticks([])
    axs[1, i].set_yticks([])

gs = axs[0, 0].get_subplotspec().get_gridspec()
gs.set_height_ratios([1, 0.0001, 1])
plt.tight_layout()

for ax in axs[1, :]:
    fig.delaxes(ax)
```

... which isn't perfect, but pretty close...

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I have to call ``gs.set_height_ratios()`` (and in my case also ``gs.set_width_ratios()`` for each remaining axis in the figure, in a loop. That's probably either because I have an older version of matplotlib, or because my subplots are generated sequentially with ``plt.add_subplot()``, not using ``plt.subplots()``.

Comment: Ideally your function would not generate the axes, but rather would take an axes argument.  Then you are much more flexible as to the layout.

Comment: Yes, not generating those unneeded axes would be preferable, but the function which generates them is a) fairly involved and b) part of a library and used by a lot of other code. So I can quickly hack the code which is using it but if I had started modifying the function generating the figure, I'd have had to spend more time working out what needs to change, and take a lot more care not to break it for any other scenario ... real life problems.